# How to add radio button in child list section and get value of all selected radiobuttons onClick of SUBMIT button

Tags: android

Here I do have a multiexpandable listview, I was wanted to add radio buttons in the child part and get value of all selected radio buttons on click of submit button (something like form POST). Can someone help me with code

Working code :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview.Product.SubCategory;
import com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview.Product.SubCategory.ItemList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
/**
 * 
 * @author manish
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Product>pProductArrayList;
    private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList;
    private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList2;
    private LinearLayout mLinearListView;
    boolean isFirstViewClick=false;
    boolean isSecondViewClick=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLinearListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_listview);

        /**
         * 
         */

        ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Red", "20"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Blue", "50"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Red", "20"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Blue", "50"));

        ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray2=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));


        /**
         * 
         */
        pSubItemArrayList=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
        pSubItemArrayList2=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
        pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory("Color", mItemListArray));
        pSubItemArrayList2.add(new SubCategory("Cloths", mItemListArray2));
        pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory("Color", mItemListArray));
        pSubItemArrayList2.add(new SubCategory("Cloths", mItemListArray2));
        /**
         * 
         */

        pProductArrayList=new ArrayList<Product>();
        pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Emotions", pSubItemArrayList));
        pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Garments", pSubItemArrayList2));


        /***
         * adding item into listview
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < pProductArrayList.size(); i++) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);

            final TextView mProductName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            final RelativeLayout mLinearFirstArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linearFirst);
            final ImageView mImageArrowFirst=(ImageView)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.imageFirstArrow);
            final LinearLayout mLinearScrollSecond=(LinearLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);

            if(isFirstViewClick==false){
            mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
            }
            else{
                mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
            }

            mLinearFirstArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(isFirstViewClick==false){
                        isFirstViewClick=true;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        isFirstViewClick=false;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
                    }
                    return false;
                } 
            });


            final String name = pProductArrayList.get(i).getpName();
            mProductName.setText(name);

            /**
             * 
             */
            for (int j = 0; j < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().size(); j++) {

                LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
                inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mLinearView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);

                TextView mSubItemName = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                final RelativeLayout mLinearSecondArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linearSecond);
                final ImageView mImageArrowSecond=(ImageView)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.imageSecondArrow);
                final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird=(LinearLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);

                if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                    mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                    }
                    else{
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                    }

                mLinearSecondArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                            if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                                isSecondViewClick=true;
                                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }else{
                                isSecondViewClick=false;
                                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                            }
                            return false;
                        } 
                    });


                final String catName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getpSubCatName();
                mSubItemName.setText(catName);
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                  for (int k = 0; k < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().size(); k++) {

                        LayoutInflater inflater3 = null;
                        inflater3 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View mLinearView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);

                        TextView mItemName = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                        TextView mItemPrice = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemPrice);
                        final String itemName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemName();
                        final String itemPrice = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemPrice();
                        mItemName.setText(itemName);
                        mItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);

                        mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearView3);
                  }

                mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearView2);

            }

            mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
        }       
    }

}
```

Product.java

```
package com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * 
 * first level item
 * 
 */
public class Product {

    private String pName;

    private ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubCategoryList;

    public Product(String pName, ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubCategoryList) {
        super();
        this.pName = pName;
        this.mSubCategoryList = mSubCategoryList;
    }

    public String getpName() {
        return pName;
    }

    public void setpName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    public ArrayList<SubCategory> getmSubCategoryList() {
        return mSubCategoryList;
    }

    public void setmSubCategoryList(ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubCategoryList) {
        this.mSubCategoryList = mSubCategoryList;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * second level item
     * 
     */

    public static class SubCategory {

        private String pSubCatName;
        private ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray;

        public SubCategory(String pSubCatName,
                ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray) {
            super();
            this.pSubCatName = pSubCatName;
            this.mItemListArray = mItemListArray;
        }

        public String getpSubCatName() {
            return pSubCatName;
        }

        public void setpSubCatName(String pSubCatName) {
            this.pSubCatName = pSubCatName;
        }

        public ArrayList<ItemList> getmItemListArray() {
            return mItemListArray;
        }

        public void setmItemListArray(ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray) {
            this.mItemListArray = mItemListArray;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * third level item
         * 
         */
        public static class ItemList {

            private String itemName;
            private String itemPrice;

            public ItemList(String itemName, String itemPrice) {
                super();
                this.itemName = itemName;
                this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
            }

            public String getItemName() {
                return itemName;
            }

            public void setItemName(String itemName) {
                this.itemName = itemName;
            }

            public String getItemPrice() {
                return itemPrice;
            }

            public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
                this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

row_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearFirst"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageFirstArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearSecond"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageSecondArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_scroll_third"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row_third.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItemName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItemPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use always this solution, hope it will be helpfull for you!

MainActivity should extends `FragmentActivity` and have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

than i add MyFragment to the container of MainActivity in this way:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MyFragment())
                .commit();
```

MyFragment will extends `ListFragment`. Now you have to create a customListAdapter like this:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int MAX_COUNT = 1;

private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();

public CustomListHomeAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(final HomeModel item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return TYPE_ITEM;      
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return MAX_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if(convertView == null) {
        //initialize the view Holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_home, null);   //HERE YOU CAN INFLATE YOUR CUSTOM LAYOUT FOR A SINGLE ROW

                viewHolder.rb = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

                break;
        }

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HomeModel model;
    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
             viewHolder.rb.setChecked(true);
        break;

    }
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    RadioButton rb;
}
}
```

And finally in your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //initialize all home items
    mAdapter = new CustomListHomeAdapter(getActivity());

    Resources resources = getResources();

    mAdapter.addItem(new HomeModel(getString(R.string.produttori_label), resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.produttori)));


    //initialize and set list adapter
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Comment: What am i asking and what you are answering. Where is Radiobutton in your answer....??

Comment: edited. As i insert in the post, you can inflate your custom layout of a single row instead of list_row_home and than that layout will be repeated for each row of your list